# Facebook share full size image with a quote

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to be able to have a link on my website that upon clicking it opens a Facebook share dialog containing the image **displayed with full size along with a custom text quote**.

The 2 options that I tried with the [Facebook share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) don't achieve that result:

1. The first option is to use `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=3xxxxxx334&quote=Some%20quote&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsome_page`, and use `og:image` tag on `www.example.com/some_page` with the image that I want to display

   - **The problem with this approach is that the image is displayed cropped** to match the aspect ratio that the Facebook uses (1.9:1) which is different than the aspect ratio that I use for the image (1.3:1)
2. The second option is to use `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=3xxxxxx334&media=[%27https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsome_img.jpg%27]` with the link of the image that I want to display

   - This approach displays the image in full size in Facebook, however **the problem is that it doesn't allow adding any text quote with the image**, any use of `quote` or `description` query parameters seems to be ignored by Facebook

So my question is there a way to combine the 2 methods such that the image gets displayed with full size along with a custom text quote?